# Android / google maps - overlay z-fighting issue?

Tags: android, maps, overlay, android-mapview

A weird one for you. I have a mapview, I draw some lines on it to link some locations, I draw a label in a box at the final location. The box is a red outline over a slightly transparent rect, with red text in it.

On 4.2 (I haven't tested it it on other versions yet) the background of the box flashes between black and white - kind of quickly/intermittently like a faulty strip light. Looks like the background to the box is kind of z-fighting with something:

[image: Alternates between these states]

Not sure if the code will help but:

```
// draw (fill) a trans grey box
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setFlags(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setARGB(200, 255, 255, 255);

canvas.drawRect(rBox, paint);

if (colour == 0) // ie one loc only, pin is green/red, label should be red
    paint.setColor (colourRed);
else
    paint.setColor (colour);


// draw the box and text
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
//paint.setColor(colour);

canvas.drawRect(rBox, paint);

// draw the text
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
canvas.drawText(sLabel, pt.x, pt.y, paint);
```

Does that ring any bells with anyone? I haven't seen anything like it before on maps. This is on a Nexus 4.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Baz